# Windows/Mac file io byte for byte POSIX compatible?

Tags: windows, macos, filesystems, posix, endianness

I want to write a cross platform file IO utility using POSIX.  I was wondering if a file I wrote on Windows could be moved to OS X (via email or a thumbdrive) and still appear to contain the exact same content?  And how about if I moved a file from OS X to Windows?

Also, are there any weird UTF-8 anomalies on either platform that I should be aware of when writing strings to this file?

This question is to be answered only for newer Macs, not the PowerPC Macs.  I just want to make sure that all the endianness and related byte ordering problems died with PowerPC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your POSIX code uses the 'binary' flag when opening the file for writing, and both machines have the same endianness (which is true for modern Intel-based Macs and Intel-based Windows PCs), then yes, files should be byte-for-byte identical.

As for UTF-8, the main thing to be aware of is that in general, Windows prefers pre-composed characters ("normalisation form NFC") while Mac OS prefers de-composed characters ("normalisation form NFD"). That is, Windows will encode "é" as U+00E9 LATIN SMALL LETTER E WITH ACUTE, while Mac OS will encode it as U+0065 LATIN SMALL LETTER E followed by U+0301 COMBINING ACUTE ACCENT. Obviously both OSs will render both sequences the same way, but I believe this affects characters entered by the user, or read from filenames on-disk.

As for endianness-related problems dying with PowerPC, that's not strictly true. ARM at least can operate in either endianness, and while, say, iOS tends to use little-endian (to match Intel), other OSs might run in big-endian mode, and some (such as Linux) can be compiled either way. Wikipedia doesn't mention which endianness Android devices typically use.